# mysql join and count field values

Tags: mysql, join

Very new to using mysql, so please excuse me if this question is really elementary. It would be great if someone could at least suggest what topic I should be researching.

I have 3 tables, user, computer, component. (this is just an example).

```
user        computer      component
----        -------       ----
id          id            id
firstName   user_id       computer_id
lastName    name          componentName
            type          componentValue
```

A user may have multiple computers, which in turn may have multiple properties.

I am trying to write a query that can get all user ids who have all of their 'Macintosh' computers contain all 'ram' components with '16GB' values.

So far I am struggling with getting the counts right, but have written something like this:

```
select user.id from user
inner join computer on user.id=computer.user_id and computer.name='Macintosh' 
inner join component on computer.id=component.computer_id and component.componentName='ram'
having count(component.propertyName='ram')=count(component.propertyValue='16GB');
```

Thanks in advance for any constructive feedback.

Comment: Why use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`??  What's the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter for componentValue = '16GB'

```
select user.id 
from user
inner join computer on user.id=computer.user_id and computer.name='Macintosh' 
inner join component on computer.id=component.computer_id 
      and component.componentName='ram'
      and  component.componentValue =  '16GB'
```

and if you want only the use that have computer with only 16GB ram  you could use

```
select user.id 
from user
inner join computer on user.id=computer.user_id and computer.name='Macintosh' 
        and computer.id not ( 
    select component.computer_id 
    from component 
    where component.componentName='ram'
          and  component.componentValue <>  '16GB')
```

Comment: The issue with this would be that there may be some computers with some ram having 8GB, and another ram having 16GB. This will still report the user id but I would not want a user who had a macintosh computer with any mixed ram values.

Comment: So you want only computer that have only 16GB ram ??

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry if that was unclear. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge, this will accomplish what I was attempting to do!